# Using the 1st random number to chose the initial state, X0, at random

Tags: random, probability, uniform

I have this probability problem:

On any given day Eric is either cheerful (C), so-so (S), or glum (G).

If he is cheerful today, then he will be C, S, or G tomorrow with respective probabilities 0.5, 0.3, 0.2.

If he is feeling so-so today, then he will be C, S, or G tomorrow with probabilities 0.3, 0.4, 0.3.

If he is glum today, then he will be C, S, or G tomorrow with probabilities 0.2, 0.2, 0.6.

I have generated 50,000 independent pseudo-random numbers (uniform) in R and have printed out the first 40. Now, how do I use the 1st random number to chose the initial state X0 at random (1/3 probability for
each state)? I know that this is equivalent to generating a discrete random variable, but I am still confused.

Comment: What is the range for the 50000 random numbers you have generated?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your random numbers are floats in the range 0 to 1. If so, it's easy to get an integer in the range of 0 to n - 1: just divide each number by 1/n and take the floor (i.e. integer part) of that.

If 1 is a possible value of the input, you would get n from floor(1/(1/n)). If that's a problem, just throw it out and generate another random number.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that this is equivalent to generating a discrete random variable, but I am still confused.

not quite

you could generate state directly from U(0,1) without going to discrete sampling. Please change state to whatever you want to use in your code (integer? some factor?)

```
initial_state <- function(r) {
    state <- "G"
    if (r < 1.0/3.0) {
        state <- "C"
    }
    else {
        if (r < 2.0/3.0)
            state <- "S"
    }
    state
}
```